# Interpolation between two images (Numpy arrays)

Tags: image, numpy, interpolation

I have two images represented by numpy arrays. Images were recorded by a camera using different exposure times (say 1sec., 2sec). I would like to interpolate linearily between the images, in order to get an image of say exposuretime 1.5 sec.
Using a for loop going through each image pixel I solved the problem like this:

```
# interpolation between two images recorded with different exposure times
import numpy as np
import time

imageSize = 3
image1 = np.zeros([imageSize,imageSize]) # first image here represented by 3x3 zeros
image2 = np.ones([imageSize,imageSize]) # second image here represented by 3x3 ones
imageStack = np.dstack([image1,image2]) # image stack
exposureTimes = np.array([1,2]) # exposure time for first image, exposure time for second image
interpolatedImage = np.zeros(image1.shape) # initialize intepolated image
exposureTime = 1.53 # the exposure time to which images should be interpolated to (here any number between 1 and 2 would be allowed)

timeBeforeLoop = time.time() # runtime monitor
for i in range(len(interpolatedImage)): # running through image columns
    for j in range(len(interpolatedImage[0])): # running through image lines
        interpolatedValueij = np.interp(exposureTime,exposureTimes,imageStack[i,j]) # pixelwise interpolation values
        interpolatedImage[i,j] = interpolatedValueij # filling the interpolated image
timeAfterLoop = time.time() # runtime monitor
runTime = timeAfterLoop - timeBeforeLoop # runtime monitor

print ('Runtime: '+str(runTime))
```

that works fine as long as the images are small enough, but for large images (1000x1000) it takes a long time (increasing imageSize to 1000 needs roughly 6 seconds on my workstation).

Is there a more efficient way to do this avoiding the for loop?

Answer (score 1):

Since the interpolation is linear, you can just take a weighted average of the two images in a single operation

```
interpolatedImage = (image2 * (exposureTime - exposureTimes[0]) + \
        image1 * (exposureTimes[1] - exposureTime) / \
        (exposureTimes[1] - exposureTimes[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the interpolation manually

```
interpolatedImage = (image2-image1) * (exposureTime -exposureTimes[0]) \
                        / (exposureTimes[1] - exposureTimes[0]) + image1
```

It cost 60ms in my desktop comparing to originally 3.29s

Answer (score 1):

Be aware of the dtype if your arrays are integers (aka images)
A linear interpolation would be the mean/average between the two unless you want some weighting of some kind.

```
a = np.random.randint(0,10, (3,3), dtype=np.int8)
b = np.random.randint(0,10, (3,3), dtype=np.int8)
ab = np.dstack((a,b))
np.mean(ab, axis=2, dtype=ab.dtype) 
array([[7, 5, 3],
       [5, 3, 3],
       [7, 3, 6]], dtype=int8)

a 
array([[6, 6, 3],
       [6, 2, 6],
       [8, 3, 7]], dtype=int8)
b
array([[9, 5, 3],
       [5, 4, 1],
       [7, 4, 5]], dtype=int8)
```